# preventDefault() is not working giving object does not support this property

Tags: jquery

I want to set maximum length of a textbox to 7 and stop further keys entering and using preventDefault but its giving error
My Code is below

```
function crInputRK(ctrlid, ControlValue, size, clsName)                                    {

    var newTextBox = crE('input');
    newTextBox.type = 'text';
    newTextBox.style.fontSize = ".9em";
    newTextBox.style['width'] = size;
    newTextBox.style['height'] = '12px';
    newTextBox.style['float'] = 'none';
    newTextBox.style['margin'] = '0 0 0 10px';//added on 13feb2012
    //newTextBox.maxLength = '3';
    newTextBox.id = ctrlid;

    newTextBox.className = 'inputDate';

    //newTextBox.onchange = "javascript:return EnableButton();";

    //ControlValue = getControlValue(ctrlid);
    if (ControlValue != "")
        newTextBox.value = ControlValue;
    if (ControlValue == "Multiple")
        newTextBox.disabled = true;
      newTextBox.setAttribute("onkeypress", "javascript:SetMaxLength(event,this);");


    return newTextBox;
}


function SetMaxLength(e, txtbox)                                                           {

    var MaxLength = 7;
    if (_$(txtbox.id).value.length >= MaxLength) {
        e.preventDefault();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an option:

```
var MaxLength = 7;
if (_$(txtbox.id).value.length >= MaxLength) {
  _$(txtbox.id).value = _$(txtbox.id).value.substring(0, MaxLength);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Input fields that require monitoring of keystrokes needs to be evaluated under the scope of 'on' (jQuery 1.7+) or 'live' (jQuery 1.4.2-1.7). If you don't, the input field will only be evaluated on page load. So you need to monitor the input doing something like...

```
function SetMaxLength(e,txtbox){
  var MaxLength = 7;
  $("#"+_$(txtbox.id)).live('keyup', function(e){
    if (_$(txtbox.id).value.length >= MaxLength) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
}
```

This will monitor your field for all actions, and if the length is greater than MaxLength it will not perform the default actions.

Answer (score 0):

`event.preventDefault` isn't cross browser compatible if you need to support older Internet Explorer versions, try using events instead (assuming you have jQuery available):

```
jQuery(newTextBox).bind('keypress', SetMaxLength);
```

Your `SetMaxLength` function will then run in the scope of the text box rather than having it passed as an argument:

```
function SetMaxLength(e, txtbox) {
  var MaxLength = 7;
  if (this.value.length >= MaxLength) {
    return false; // or e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using .preventDefault();

```
 $("body").find("input[type=text]").each(function(k,v) {
     $(this).on('keypress', function(event) {
        limit = 7; //for example
        val = $(this).val();
        len = val.length;
        if(len > limit-1) { event.preventDefault(); }
             });
    });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/P5sjx/)